# referencing another sheet using indirect formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to referencing another sheet using this indirect formula

```
=indirect("'"&L2&"'!"&B74)
```

it works with simple name sheet like: m

but doesn't work with the name I want:

```
animated ad units 10rd of Feb
```

I have been desperately trying for the whole day but got no success.

Please help me

Comment: sorry for my stupidity. i know why it wont work. 
the sheet name is : animated ad units 10rd of Feb

Answer (score 1):

all you need is:

```
=INDIRECT(L2&"!B74")
```

[image: 0]